# ImportError: cannot import name 'object_detector' from 'mediapipe_model_maker' during initial import

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to follow [this tutorial here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mediapipe/blob/main/examples/customization/object_detector.ipynb) to train a tensorflow lite object detection model using mediapipe.

I set up the environment as described [here](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python) using Anaconda.

I am using Pycharm on Windows and the following packages:

```
Python 3.10.13
Tensorflow 2.10.1
Mediapipe 0.9.0.1
Mediapipe-model-maker 0.1.0.2
```

I tried to run the code but I don't even get past the import statement.

```
import os
import json
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches, text, patheffects
from collections import defaultdict
import math

#the line below seems to be the issue
from mediapipe_model_maker import object_detector

assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')
```

I get the following error:

```
    from mediapipe_model_maker import object_detector
ImportError: cannot import name 'object_detector' from 'mediapipe_model_maker' (C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\object_detection_mediapipe\lib\site-packages\mediapipe_model_maker\__init__.py)
```

I found a thread on the same issue [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/error-running-mediapipe-model-maker/17699/3) and tried the things suggested but the error remains.

So I followed the path from the error message above to have a look `__init__.py` file.

It only has the following content, which is less than I expected, which is why I am sharing it (it's not necessarily the source of the issue):

```
#content of the __init__.py file \Anaconda3\envs\object_detection_mediapipe\lib\site-packages\mediapipe_model_maker\__init__.py

from mediapipe_model_maker.python.core.utils import quantization
from mediapipe_model_maker.python.vision import image_classifier
from mediapipe_model_maker.python.vision import gesture_recognizer
from mediapipe_model_maker.python.text import text_classifier
```

So if anyone has an idea on how to resolve the error, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What is your `mediapipe-model-maker` version?

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine See above, mediapipe-model-maker 0.1.0.2 :)

Comment: Oops..Apologies:)

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of mediapipe-model-maker: Make sure that you have installed the correct version of mediapipe-model-maker that is compatible with your version of tensorflow , matplotlib and others.